# Firefox url bar font

Tags: firefox

How to change font size in Firefox address/url bar only?

There are ways to increase pixel size & other ones, but I need only for address (URL) bar.

No addons installation please.

Comment: why people are down-voting? what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Gnome UI, Firefox is using default system font for address/URL bar.
A good way to change it if you are using Gnome UI is:

- install 'Gnome Tweaks' (go to Software and search for 'gnome tweaks'
- open the Tweaks app
- go to Fonts tab
- update 'Interface Text' value (as per picture below)

[image: Fonts tab in Tweaks tool]